# Verification of the formula of variation of parameters for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, fundamental-solution

**Background**

Consider the non homogeneous linear ODE in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

$$\dot{\xi}(t) = A(t)\xi(t) + \nu(t)\; \xi(\sigma_0) = x_0 \label{1}\tag{I}$$

With $A$ a matrix of size $n\times n$ whose entries are measurable and locally essentially bounded functions, and $\nu$ vector of $n$ locally integrable functions.

The solution of this problem is given by the *variation of parameters formula*:

$$ \xi(t) = \Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 + \int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(t,s)\nu(s) \, ds $$

Where $\Phi(t,\sigma)$ is the *fundamental solution* of the homogeneous case of the system in $\eqref{1}$ i.e $\dot{\xi}(t) = A(t)\xi(t)$, $\xi(\sigma) = x_0$. More explicitly, $\Phi(t,\sigma_0)$ fulfills that $(\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0)\dot{} = A(t)\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0,$ with $\Phi(\sigma_0,\sigma_0)x_0 = x_0$.

**My question/problem**

So I was trying to verify the variation of parameters formula, that is, I was trying to see that indeed

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 + \int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(t,s)\nu(s) \, ds\right) = A(t)\left(\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 + \int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(t,s)\nu(s) \, ds\right) + \nu(t) \label{2}\tag{II}$$

**And my problem is that I can't prove \eqref{2}.**

Of course, what one should do is to simply develop, so here is my try:

- LHS

\begin{align}
    & \phantom{\; = \;}\dot{\xi}(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 + \int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(t,s)\nu(s) \, ds\right) = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0\right) + \frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(t,s)\nu(s) \, ds\right)\\
    & = A(t)\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 +  \Phi(t,t)\nu(t)  \text{ (1}^{\text{st}}\text{  fundamental theorem of calculus)}\\
    & = A(t)\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 +  \nu(t).
\end{align}

- RHS

\begin{align}
    & \phantom{\; = \;}A(t)\xi(t) + \nu(t) = A(t)\left(\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 + \int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(t,s)\nu(s) \, ds\right) + \nu(t)\\ 
    & = A(t)\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 + \int_{\sigma_0}^t A(t)\Phi(t,s)\nu(s) \, ds + \nu(t).
\end{align}

Here I don't know what to do. There are useful properties like $\Phi(t,s)^{-1} = \Phi(s,t)$, but I don't see how to use them.

I know there are a lot of questions about the variation of parameters formula:

[How to derive the variation of parameters formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467422/how-to-derive-the-variation-of-parameters-formula),

[Approach of Variation of parameters (Variation of Constants)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057043/approach-of-variation-of-parameters-variation-of-constants),

[First Order ODE - Variation Of Parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103503/first-order-ode-variation-of-parameters).

but as far as I've seen nobody has asked about this verification, it should be simple (so say all the books of theory of ODE that I've consulted) but I don't see how to proceed.

Any hints? what am I missing?

*If this is a duped question my apologies.*

**EDIT (one day later).**

Ok, after 24 hours, I think I manage to see how to do it. First, indeed in the RHS we have that:

\begin{align}
    & \phantom{\; = \;}A(t)\xi(t) + \nu(t) = A(t)\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 +  A(t)\int_{\sigma_0}^t\Phi(t,s)\nu(s) \, ds + \nu(t).
\end{align}

The trick is in the LHS: using the fact that $\Phi(t,s) = \Phi(t,\sigma_0)\Phi(\sigma_0,s)$ for any $t,s,\sigma_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, we can see that:

\begin{align}
\dot{\xi}(t) & =\frac{d}{dt}\left(\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 + \int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(t,s)\nu(s) \, ds\right) = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0\right) + \frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(t,s)\nu(s) \, ds\right)\\
    & = A(t)\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 +   \frac{d}{dt}\left( \Phi(t,\sigma_0)\int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(\sigma_0,s)\nu(s) \, ds\right)\\
& = A(t)\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 +   \frac{d}{dt}\left( \Phi(t,\sigma_0)\right)\int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(\sigma_0,s)\nu(s) \, ds + \Phi(t,\sigma_0)\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(\sigma_0,s)\nu(s) \, ds\right) \; \text{(derivative product rule)}\\
& = A(t)\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 + A(t)\Phi(t,\sigma_0)\int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(\sigma_0,s)\nu(s) \, ds + \Phi(t,\sigma_0)\Phi(\sigma_0,t)\nu(t)\\
& = A(t)\Phi(t,\sigma_0)x_0 + A(t)\int_{\sigma_0}^t \Phi(t,s)\nu(s) \, ds + \nu(t)
\end{align}

Wich proves \eqref{2}.

So I suppose I just answered my own question.

Going to leave the question in case someone sees something weird in my procedure. And in case it helps someone else.